# When executing a bash shell script in ubuntu 18.04, the location parameter doesn't work, how can I solve this problem?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

The name of the script is InstallmDNS.sh

The script content is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

sethostname() {
  if [ $# -eq 1 ]
  then
    hostnamectl set-hostname "$1"
    sed -i "/127.0.1.1/d" /etc/hosts
    sed -i "/127.0.0.1/a\127.0.1.1    $1" /etc/hosts
    reboot
  else
    echo "The exapmle of execute the script:  bash InstallmDNS.sh server1"
    echo "This script is executed with one parameter."
    exit 0
  fi
}

dia=`systemctl status avahi-daemon|grep Active`
if [[ "$dia" =~ "running" ]]
then
  echo "mDNS is running"
  sethostname
else
  apt-get install avahi-daemon -y
  echo "mDNS installation complete."
  sethostname
fi
```

I run the script:

```
root@linux:/home/ankon# bash InstallmDNS.sh
mDNS is running
The exapmle of execute the script:  bash InstallmDNS.sh server1
This script is executed with one parameter.
```

I run the script with parameters:

```
root@linux:/home/ankon# bash InstallmDNS.sh server2
mDNS is running
The exapmle of execute the script:  bash InstallmDNS.sh server1
This script is executed with one parameter.
```

I added the parameters and ran the script, but the parameters didn't do anything, what caused this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing parameters to script is different from passing parameters to a function inside the script.

The parameters given to the script are not "auto-passed" to the function.

You are expecting $1 to be `server2` the value you passed to the script, but actually you are not passing any parameter to the function when it's called

```
if [[ "$dia" =~ "running" ]]
then
  echo "mDNS is running"
  sethostname <---- This line should pass the arguments
else
  apt-get install avahi-daemon -y
  echo "mDNS installation complete."
  sethostname <---- This line should pass the arguments
fi
```

The pointed out lines should be changed to

```
sethostname $1
```

Comment: Or better to `sethostname "$1"`.